# MVC4 adding Nested Lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MainViewModel class structured like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
       ...some properties
       private ObservableCollection<Strike> m_strikes;
    public ObservableCollection<Strike> Strikes
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.m_strikes == null)
                this.m_strikes = new ObservableCollection<Strike>();
            return this.m_strikes;
        }
    }
}
public class Strike
{
    private ObservableCollection<Reivindication> m_reivindications;
    public ObservableCollection<Reivindication> Reivindications
    {
        get { return m_reivindications; }
        set
        {
            m_reivindications = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Reivindications");
        }
    }
private ObservableCollection<StrikeDate> m_stikeDates;
        public ObservableCollection<StrikeDate> StrikeDates
        {
            get { return m_stikeDates; }
            set
            {
                m_stikeDates = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("StrikeDates");
            }
        }      
    }
```

the classes Reivindication and StrikeDates have some properties not relevant to the issue.

I have a partial view that renders the MainViewModel model:

```
    @model Models.MainViewModel
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <img src="~/Images/someimage.png" height="300" style="position:absolute" />

    <section id="loginForm" style="position:relative;width:685px;height:600px;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <div style="position:relative;top:270px;" id="strikesDiV">
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Strike...","AddStrike","Home",
                new { containerPrefix = this.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"], @class="addStrikeItem"},
                new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "strikesDiV" }, 
                null)
            @foreach (Models.Strike strike in Model.Strikes)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_StrikePartial", strike);
            }
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="k-button" value="Save" style="position:absolute; left:620px;top:0px;" />
    }
    </section>
</div>
```

My _StrikePartial view has:

```
    @using Report.Helpers
@model Models.Strike
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />
<div class="editorRow" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;min-height:100px;overflow:auto;">
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("Strikes"))
{
    <text>Identification</text> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Identification,  new {data_containerPrefix=this.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"]}) <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>  

    <div style="top:10px;" id="reivindicationsDiV">

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Reivindication...", "AddReivindication", "Home",
                new { containerPrefix = this.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"], @class="addReivindicationItem"},
                new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "reivindicationsDiV"},
                new { style = "float:right" })
            @foreach (Models.Reivindication reivindication in Model.Reivindications)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_ReivindicationPartial", reivindication);
            }
        </div>


    <div style="top:10px;" id="strikeDatesDiV">
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Add strike date...","AddStrikeDate","Home",
                new { containerPrefix = this.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"], @class="addStrikeDateItem"},
                new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "strikeDatesDiV" }, 
                new { style="float:right" })
            @foreach (Models.StrikeDate strikeDate in Model.StrikeDates)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_StrikeDatePartial", strikeDate);
            }
        </div>
}
</div>
<script>
    $("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
        $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and one of the partials (_ReivindicationPartial):

```
@using Report.Helpers
@model Models.Reivindication
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />
<div class="reivindicationEditorRow">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Reivindications"))
{
    <text>Reivindication code</text> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { style="width:150px", data_containerPrefix=this.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"]}) 
    <text>Result</text> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Outcome, new { style="width:150px" , data_containerPrefix=this.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"]}) 
    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>  
}
</div>
<script>
    $("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
        $(this).parents("div.reivindicationEditorRow:first").remove();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and I have this helper class:

```
public static class HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions
    {
        private const string idsToReuseKey = "__htmlPrefixScopeExtensions_IdsToReuse_";

        public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName)
        {
            if (html.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"] != null)
            {
                collectionName = string.Concat(html.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"], ".", collectionName);
            }

            var idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName);
            string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var htmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex);
            html.ViewData["ContainerPrefix"] = htmlFieldPrefix;

            // autocomplete="off" is needed to work around a very annoying Chrome behaviour whereby it reuses old values after the user clicks "Back", which causes the xyz.index and xyz[...] values to get out of sync.
            html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}.index\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"{1}\" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex)));

            return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, htmlFieldPrefix);
        }

        public static IDisposable BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            return new HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
        }

        private static Queue<string> GetIdsToReuse(HttpContextBase httpContext, string collectionName)
        {
            // We need to use the same sequence of IDs following a server-side validation failure,  
            // otherwise the framework won't render the validation error messages next to each item.
            string key = idsToReuseKey + collectionName;
            var queue = (Queue<string>)httpContext.Items[key];
            if (queue == null)
            {
                httpContext.Items[key] = queue = new Queue<string>();
                var previouslyUsedIds = httpContext.Request[collectionName + ".index"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouslyUsedIds))
                    foreach (string previouslyUsedId in previouslyUsedIds.Split(','))
                        queue.Enqueue(previouslyUsedId);
            }
            return queue;
        }

        private class HtmlFieldPrefixScope : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly TemplateInfo templateInfo;
            private readonly string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

            public HtmlFieldPrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
            {
                this.templateInfo = templateInfo;

                previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;
            }
        }
    }
```

in my Home controller I add an item like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public PartialViewResult AddStrike(string containerPrefix)
        {
            ViewData["ContainerPrefix"] = containerPrefix;
            return PartialView("_StrikePartial", new Strike());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public PartialViewResult AddReivindication(string containerPrefix)
        {
            ViewData["ContainerPrefix"] = containerPrefix;
            return PartialView("_ReivindicationPartial", new Reivindication());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public PartialViewResult AddStrikeDate(string containerPrefix)
        {
            ViewData["ContainerPrefix"] = containerPrefix;
            return PartialView("_StrikeDatePartial", new StrikeDate());
        }
```

If I add the first Strike and inside the strike I add a reivindication it renders OK.
If I add a second Strike and inside the second one I add a reivindication, the page renders the new reivindication in the first strike. But, if I click Save, the MainViewModel is correct. In debug the Strike[1].Reivindications[0] appears correct.
Only the rendering is wrong.
here's the render page:

```
div id="reivindicationsDiV" style="top: 10px;">
        Principais reivindicações expressas e resultados obtidos
            <a style="float: right;" href="/Report/Home/AddReivindication?containerPrefix=Strikes%5Bd3fc7e4a-0571-40cb-9b2d-b4383b22eae8%5D&amp;class=addReivindicationItem" data-ajax-update="#reivindicationsDiV" data-ajax-mode="after" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax="true">Adicionar Reivindicação...</a>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css">




<div class="reivindicationEditorRow">
<input name="Strikes[d3fc7e4a-0571-40cb-9b2d-b4383b22eae8].Reivindications.index" type="hidden" value="dd1716b2-a832-4f2a-8b99-f230b20df2b5" autocomplete="off">
    Reivindicação <input name="Strikes[d3fc7e4a-0571-40cb-9b2d-b4383b22eae8].Reivindications[dd1716b2-a832-4f2a-8b99-f230b20df2b5].Code" id="Strikes_d3fc7e4a-0571-40cb-9b2d-b4383b22eae8__Reivindications_dd1716b2-a832-4f2a-8b99-f230b20df2b5__Code" style="width: 150px;" type="text" value="11" data-val-number="The field Code must be a number." data-val="true" data-containerprefix="Strikes[d3fc7e4a-0571-40cb-9b2d-b4383b22eae8].Reivindications[dd1716b2-a832-4f2a-8b99-f230b20df2b5]">    Resultado <input name="Strikes[d3fc7e4a-0571-40cb-9b2d-b4383b22eae8].Reivindications[dd1716b2-a832-4f2a-8b99-f230b20df2b5].Outcome" id="Strikes_d3fc7e4a-0571-40cb-9b2d-b4383b22eae8__Reivindications_dd1716b2-a832-4f2a-8b99-f230b20df2b5__Outcome" style="width: 150px;" type="text" value="12" data-val-number="The field Outcome must be a number." data-val="true" data-containerprefix="Strikes[d3fc7e4a-0571-40cb-9b2d-b4383b22eae8].Reivindications[dd1716b2-a832-4f2a-8b99-f230b20df2b5]">    <a class="deleteRow" href="#">delete</a>  
</div>
        <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css">




<div class="reivindicationEditorRow">
<input name="Strikes[a3c19f26-f4ed-47c9-9870-d6b2d3bc0adc].Reivindications.index" type="hidden" value="4e3d2042-dce9-4143-af69-ab816a69297b" autocomplete="off">
    Reivindicação <input name="Strikes[a3c19f26-f4ed-47c9-9870-d6b2d3bc0adc].Reivindications[4e3d2042-dce9-4143-af69-ab816a69297b].Code" id="Strikes_a3c19f26-f4ed-47c9-9870-d6b2d3bc0adc__Reivindications_4e3d2042-dce9-4143-af69-ab816a69297b__Code" style="width: 150px;" type="text" value="" data-val-number="The field Code must be a number." data-val="true" data-containerprefix="Strikes[a3c19f26-f4ed-47c9-9870-d6b2d3bc0adc].Reivindications[4e3d2042-dce9-4143-af69-ab816a69297b]">    Resultado <input name="Strikes[a3c19f26-f4ed-47c9-9870-d6b2d3bc0adc].Reivindications[4e3d2042-dce9-4143-af69-ab816a69297b].Outcome" id="Strikes_a3c19f26-f4ed-47c9-9870-d6b2d3bc0adc__Reivindications_4e3d2042-dce9-4143-af69-ab816a69297b__Outcome" style="width: 150px;" type="text" value="" data-val-number="The field Outcome must be a number." data-val="true" data-containerprefix="Strikes[a3c19f26-f4ed-47c9-9870-d6b2d3bc0adc].Reivindications[4e3d2042-dce9-4143-af69-ab816a69297b]">    <a class="deleteRow" href="#">delete</a>  
</div>
</div>
```

The Id's seem right but the second reivindication should render in the second strikeDatesDiV (not presented here)
This is driving me crazy, any help is welcome
Thanx in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you can't safely make your question shorter?

Comment: Hi Andre, I'm trying to give all information so a don't get any generic response, maybe it's a problem with the Helper, or maybe it's a rendering problem, I don't really know for sure. I thought I did everything right with the info I found but something is missing here

Comment: I think I solved the problem, 
I re-read this link http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/ 
and I started from the begining... I replace the ActionLinks by inputs and made the contoller call in javascript, replace RenderPartial by EditorRor, made editortemplates for the models, made new partials for each model containing the EditorForModel... the link has the source code to download and I startedalmost everything from scratch looking at the downloadable project :)